# How do you dynamically assign an ngmodel by dot separated path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model

I have seen several questions similar to this but my question is slightly different.

I have an object on my controller that looks something like this:

```
$scope.data = {
  foo: {bar: 1,
        bas: 2},
  biz: 3,
  blat: 4
};
```

I would like to create an input that can have its ng-model dynamically assigned to any of those values.

```
<label>Define Model</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="input.model" />

<label>Data for {{input.model}}:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="{{input.model}}">
```

Ideally this would allow me to set the "Define Model" input to something like `data.foo.bas` and the "Data for data.foo.bas" input would have a value of 2.

I am aware I can do something like this:

```
<label>Define Model</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="input.model" />

<label>Data for {{input.model}}:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="data[input.model]">
```

but this would only allow me to access the biz and blat attributes.  Does anyone have any ideas how this might be done?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse)

```
$scope.$watch('input.model', function(newVal) {
    $scope.definedModel = $parse(newVal)($scope.data);
});
```

here `$parse` try to match the value from `$scope.data` and bind it with `definedModel`

demo [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tt7osejwtEwOqMaYhFVn?p=preview)

Comment: Don't forget that the model also needs to update on change; see http://plnkr.co/edit/rw8oCqNNq2V4kk7miS8O?p=preview

Comment: Thanks to both @BrandonTilley and Reza.  That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but only if you slightly modify the form of your data array, so that each model has its own object (and not just a primitive), with a common structure:

```
var data = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      value: 1
    },
    bas: {
      value: 2
    }
  },
  biz: {
    value: 3
  },
  blat: {
    value: 4
  }
};
```

This is so you can pass the objects around so `ngModel` can still reference (and so change) the original object.

You then need a function to convert a "path" of like "foo.bas", to return the correct object, [modified from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6491615/1319998):

```
var getProperty = function(obj, prop) {
  var parts = prop.split('.'),
      last = parts.pop(),
      l = parts.length,
      i = 1,
      current = parts[0];

  if (l === 0) return obj[prop];

  while((obj = obj[current]) && i < l) {
      current = parts[i];
      i++;
  }

  if(obj) {
      return obj[last];
  }
}
```

And you then have to watch the `input.model` variable, to make sure that the scope's `model` variable is set to the right object:

```
$scope.$watch('input.model', function(name) {
  $scope.model = getProperty(data, name);
});
```

And finally this is all controlled by inputs that set "input.model" and "model" on the scope:

```
<input placeholder="Model name" ng-model="input.model" />
<input placeholder="Model value" ng-model="model.value" />
```

This can be [seen in action at this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iq2M4nHXnCa6QgbK4lmq?p=preview)

Edit: As per [the answer from @Reza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20878198/1319998) , you can use `$parse` instead of the `getProperty` function above. Using this, the watcher can be

```
$scope.$watch('input.model', function(name) {
  $scope.model = $parse(name)(data);
});
```

which can be seen [in this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dGglJFNpFPI4F2lrxzWW?p=preview). I have to admit it's a nicer way with less code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try recompiling the element with the ng-model attribute you want: https://gist.github.com/djdmbrwsk/9a7004492a709044e597